# How to add consultants to AWS CodeCommit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-codecommit

I work on the project that is entirely stored and run on AWS. I need to add a few software consultants to my AWS CodeCommit. All I want them to do is to be able to work on a few repositories at that's it. I don't even want to give them power to create/delete repositories.

What is the best strategy to create such users, only for CodeCommit, so I don't give them too much power? 
Should I create a group for them?

Thanks for help

EDIT: When creating the user It looks like I have to pick between "Programmatic access" and "AWS Management Console access" - both sounds powerful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Granting programatic and/or console access isn't really saying a whole lot. Neither of those things give a user the ability to do much of anything. The key is in the permissions you grant them. In your case you should set up a group for these people and grant permissions to the group. If the users will only be using CodeCommit via `git` then you can make their permissions pretty limited. You may want to grant them console access to manage their own keys, but that would be about it. Here are some resources that will help you understand the permissions to grant.

- [CodeCommit Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control-permissions-reference.html)
- [Using IAM with CodeCommit: Git Credentials, SSH Keys, and AWS Access Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_ssh-keys.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will read it. But should I go with programatic and/or console access?

Comment: That really depends on your use case. Either/both could be okay, and you can change it later. It's a question of how you expect these users to interact with their accounts.

Comment: I still can't find my answer. They will be using AWS only via Git. Committing code and that's it. The only thing the will need to do is to manage their ssh key. Should I go with "AWS Management Console access"? "Programmatic access" enables an access key ID and secret access key for the AWS API, CLI, SDK, and other development tools - Idk if they need that

Comment: I think you'll want to grant them console access to have them manage their SSH keys, but you can also manage SSH keys via the CLI, which would require programatic access, not console access. So again, the answer depends on what you want to do. The easiest is probably console, but some people would rather just have it all done in the CLI.